# Code Completion with omni completion for wxpython functions in vim

Tags: vim, wxpython, omnicomplete

i have omni completion working fine for regular python functions, but how do i also get it to work for the wxpython functions?

Comment: You'll probably need to point Vim to a `tags` file generated against the wxpython libs.

Comment: does this tags file you speak of come with wxpython install?

Comment: I don't think so. You could try `$ ctags -R .` from within the source but I imagine the results are going to be big and messy.

Comment: so how do i get this wxpython tags file? sorry i'm a newb at vim...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try vim.org? It has a [Pydiction project](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=850) on there that includes wxPython autocomplete as well as several other 3rd party Python libraries.

Comment: you are the man. surprised this didn't show up during any of my google searches. got it working now, thanks a lot.